# Minecraft server - stop announcing gamemode change/item spawning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, server-administration

Is there a way to stop announcing gamemode changes, item spawning events etc. on the chat for all the players on a Minecraft Server?
I've been searching but I cannot seem to find a flag in the configuration to turn this off.

Thanks.

Comment: By default I think it should only display for opped players. Not sure if there's any way to turn it off for all players though.

Comment: Is this a vanilla Minecraft server?  What version of Minecraft?

Comment: Do take note that minecraft have been changing alot recently and we would require a version number to know what tools and command you have access to.

Comment: I am using 1.6.4, but I fixed my problem by removing the spawn protection and removing admin privileges to others. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: @Ender Why do you want to put a bounty on this, the answer is not really outdated, it still works.

Comment: because the comments say it does not, including  new question asked recently marked as a dupe linked to this. Please enlighten me?

Comment: @Ender Look at the date of that comment. On August 2014, the "current version" was 1.7. They're saying that it only works for the 1.8 prereleases/snapshots. It has continued to work since then and still does.

Comment: Ok then free rep I guess. Meh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that only other operators can actually see those messages, not all the other players of the server.

To turn it off for OPs, do:

```
/gamerule sendCommandFeedback false
```

Comment: This does not work for the current version. It is for 1.8!

Comment: I was not aware of this since I run a small server for me and my friends. Since there's spawn protection and I was not able to figure out how to disable spawn protection for certain players (I want to maintain it since, if I'm correct, it protects spawn from explosions etc.?) so I opped the players.

Comment: This should not work for any version of minecraft. This only disable self command feedback.

Comment: @ModDL Just tested it in 1.10 and it works for all players.